# socket.timeout: timed out when executing python using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, sockets, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Getting the below exception while executing, here we doing some calculation and writing the dataframe in parquet file. while saving i'm facing the socket time out issue and also tried using heartbeatInterval while executing but still didn't get resolved

20/11/17 14:50:28 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\NMR_PySpark\ARCHimedes\PySpark.Package\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 585, in main
File "C:\NMR_PySpark\ARCHimedes\PySpark.Package\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 593, in read_int
length = stream.read(4)
File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
socket.timeout: timed out

```
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

20/11/17 14:50:28 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20201117145009_0212 aborted.
20/11/17 14:50:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 212.0 (TID 452)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\NMR_PySpark\ARCHimedes\PySpark.Package\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 585, in main
File "C:\NMR_PySpark\ARCHimedes\PySpark.Package\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 593, in read_int
length = stream.read(4)
File "D:\obj\Windows-Release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
socket.timeout: timed out

```
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
    ... 9 more
```